# JSON response from PHP script

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I am building a registration system for Android. I can add data to the database,which is good. Now I want to add some JSON that will notify the user successful registration or different errors. ie

```
{
  "status":"success",
  "message":"Successful Registration"

}
```

or

```
 {
  "status":"fail",
  "message":"Please enter your name"

}
```

etc.

Here is my php script.

```
<?php
   require "init.php";
   $j = new stdClass();
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_pass = md5(md5($_POST['user_name']).$_POST['user_pass']);
    if(!$name){
    json_encode(array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'Please enter your    
    name'));
   }
   $sql_query = "insert into user_info    
  values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";

   if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)){

    json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Successfully 
    registered'));

  }else{

   json_encode(array('status' => 'fail', 'message' => 'Could not   
   register'));
  }



 ?>
```

With this script I can not detect any JSON repsonse from my Java code,even if I add data successfully.

```
  private void registerUser(final String name, final String userName,
                          final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";


    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "MY_LINK_GOES_HERE", new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Launch login activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Register.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error", "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("user_name", userName);
            params.put("user_pass", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

The line

```
Log.d("Response", "Register Response: " + response.toString());
```

gives me nothing.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: ' I can add data to the database,which is good. Now I want to add some JSON'.  To that database also?

Comment: probably he means he wants to make an array() at PHP and encode it with JSON so he can show error messages in device

Comment: Yes this is what I mean!

Comment: php's [json_encode](http://docs.php.net/json_encode) returns a string, but your script doesn't do anything with the return value. You might want to print it or assign it to a variable and then print its contents at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had encountered the same problemm in my App when i was trying to make a registration. I wanted to check if user registered and if the username is available.

So what i did was:

PHP File:

```
<?php
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dateCreated = $_POST['dateCreated'];
$android_version= $_POST['android_version'];
$api_level = $_POST['api_level'];
$check = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = '$username'");
$don = array();
     if($check->rowCount() > 0){
          $don = array('result' =>TRUE);
          die();
     }else{
          $don = array('result' =>FALSE);
          $handler->query("INSERT INTO table(id, username, password, email, dateCreated, activated, Android_Version, API_Level) VALUES('', '$username','$password','$email', '$dateCreated', 0, '$android_version', '$api_level')");
     }

echo json_encode($don);
?>
```

Android:

private class MyInsertDataTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.dialog_rate_data_submit));
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uName));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateCreated", date));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("android_version", release));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_level", String.valueOf(sdkVersion)));

        try
        {
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpPost = new HttpPost(AppConstant.REGISTER_URL);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            Log.e("Responce", result.toString());
            if (result != null) {
                data = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                usernameExists = data.getBoolean("result");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        }
        return  usernameExists;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (aVoid){
            Snackbar.with(YourActivity.this).type(SnackbarType.MULTI_LINE).text(getString(R.string.username_exists_message)).color(Color.parseColor(AppConstant.ENABLED_BUTTON_COLOR)).show(getActivity());
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, getString(R.string.created_successfully), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            YourActivity.this.finish();
        }

    }
}
```

The result is that if username exists a message pops up saying username already exists otherwise the user registers

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. It is fixed:). I wasn't printing the json response from PHP.

Comment: glad i could help you

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should mention in your question that you are using the `android-volley` library, or at least use the `tag`. Second, if you are trying to parse `JSON` response, then you should use the `JsonObjectRequest` instance to do that. Assuming your `php` script is sending  the right `JSON`, you could try  something simple and straight-forward with `volley` like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    response = response.getJSONObject("args");
                    String site = response.getString("site"), network = response.getString("network");
                    View view = findViewById(R.id.activity_layout);
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Site : " + site + " Network : " + network, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error Listener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonRequest);
```

This assumes your `JSON` is something like this:

```
{
  "args": {
    "network": "somenetwork", 
    "site": "code"
  }, 
  "args2": {
    ...
  }, 
  "args3": "...", 
  "args4": "..."
}
```

Now depending on the `JSON` you are sending, you could try any combination. You could also look into this very useful [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800). Hope this helps. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Well,I can deal the GET requests easily. POST requests though are harder...It is a bit tricky.

Comment: It  is not really hard once you get to know how volley works. In fact it is easier than most other ways. This is taking the fact that with API 23, android has deprecated ApacheHttp, volley is really your best option unless you  are doing  heavy lifting. Take a look at these tutorials (https://gist.github.com/mombrea/7250835) / (http://www.itworld.com/article/2702452/development/how-to-send-a-post-request-with-google-volley-on-android.html), you will have a good understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! It was a php issue. Here is my solution.

```
<?php
  require "init.php";
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
  $user_pass = md5(md5($_POST['user_name']).$_POST['user_pass']);

        $sql_query = "select * from user_info WHERE user_name  
  ='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user_name)."'";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query);   

        $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($results){
            $don = array('result' =>"fail","message"=>"Username exists. User               
        a different one");
        }else{

            $sql_query = "insert into user_info  
       values('$name','$user_name','$user_pass');";

            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)){

            $don = array('result' =>"success","message"=>"Successfully  
            registered!Well done");

            }
        }

    echo json_encode($don);

  ?>
```